# Running another browser along side TOR

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

If I run TOR and another browser (say Firefox) and surf on both at the same time, one downloading and surfing the other does this compromise the security/anonymity of TOR?

Comment: No, running Firefox will not affect the anonymity of the Tor Browser

Answer (score 2):

As the Tor browser uses it's own resources, and even creates an encrypted connection to the Tor network, no.

Unless, of course, you get malware in Firefox. That is the malware fault, though, and not just the fact of having two browser open